# Simplifying an equation with a volume integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics, divergence-theorem

I am deriving a specialised form of the fluid momentum conservation equation for two-phase incompressible flow. One of the terms in the equation is of the following form:
$$
\mathbf{C}(t) = \iiint_{V(t)}\! (\nabla\alpha\!\cdot\!\mathbf{x})\mathbf{u}\, dV,
$$
where $V(t)$ is a time-varying fluid control volume enclosed by a smooth boundary $S(t)$, $\mathbf{x}$ is a position vector, $\mathbf{u} \equiv \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}, t)$ is the fluid velocity, and $\alpha \equiv \alpha(\mathbf{x}, t)$ is a linearly varying (within $V(t)$) scalar field. Thus, $\nabla\alpha$ is constant within $V(t)$. Is there a way that I can simplify this triple integral further?

**Edit:**
I am essential trying to apply the finite volume method to all integral terms in the equation. This particular term is problematic as I cannot see how I can apply the Divergence theorem to it to cast it as an area integral. I am so far able to split it up into two terms - one problematic, the other not:
$$
\mathbf{C}(t) = \iiint_{V(t)}\! [\nabla(\alpha\mathbf{x}) - \alpha\nabla\!\cdot\!\mathbf{x}]\mathbf{u}\, dV,
$$

Comment: Please be a little more clear. Does $\alpha$ depend on space, time, or both?

Comment: @K.defaoite Both space and time. I have just edited and clarified in the post.

Comment: Argh. If $\alpha$ depended on space only, we would have some nice simplifications I think. Otherwise I don't think it's very clean

Comment: @K.defaoite Okay, was just trying my luck. Thanks :)